# undefined method `find_by_provder_and_uid' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following along with the tutorial here:

```
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1
```

In my controller I created the following method:

```
  def create  
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provder_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url  
  end
```

Problem is it is erroring like so:

```
undefined method `find_by_provder_and_uid' for []:Array
```

Ideas why? thanks

Comment: possibly because you misspelled "provider" in the method call?

Comment: Do you have the 'provider' and 'uid' as database fields? I think you forgot to run the migration

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that page has a typo -- it should be:

```
    current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
```

The original [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) has it spelled properly. I just e-mailed the AsciiCasts author notifying him of the typo.